# Unresolved externals after using Freetype [dupe]

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

I'm trying to render some text with freetype, I'm following this https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering basically per vadum but I'm getting compilation errors that look something like this:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Init_FreeType referenced in function "void __cdecl Game::LoadContent(void)" (?LoadContent@Game@@YAXXZ)    TrainSim    
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Done_FreeType referenced in function "void __cdecl Game::LoadContent(void)" (?LoadContent@Game@@YAXXZ)    TrainSim    
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_New_Face referenced in function "void __cdecl Game::LoadContent(void)" (?LoadContent@Game@@YAXXZ) TrainSim    
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Done_Face referenced in function "void __cdecl Game::LoadContent(void)" (?LoadContent@Game@@YAXXZ)    TrainSim    
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes referenced in function "void __cdecl Game::LoadContent(void)" (?LoadContent@Game@@YAXXZ)  TrainSim    
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol FT_Load_Char referenced in function "void __cdecl Game::LoadContent(void)" (?LoadContent@Game@@YAXXZ)    TrainSim
```

in my Include folder I have the "freetype" include folder and the "ft2build.h" file and in my libraries I have a "freetyped.lib" file

I have tried adding `msvcrt.lib` and `msvcmrt.lib` to linker additional dependencies, but that introduced even more errors.

Comment: Did you add the appropriate freetype libraries to the dependencies?

Comment: @RetiredNinja that was it, I forgot to add it, thanks!